Syncing offline app with lots of data with server
Hi fellow stackoverflowers,
We have an electron app, with a JSON DB for persisting the app's state while offline.
When the app syncs (to submit new actions & fetch new data), a new JSON is created from the server(Django), which replaces the one previously being used from the electron app.
All good up to now, the app has had lots of usage, until one of the features started exploding the size of the JSON response.
For additional context, serialising the response object to a JSON object on the server can take up to ~30sec, which will grow even more given that data adds up.
At the moment we were thinking that our best bet is to introduce websockets, move the JSON generation in the background, and send a message to the app once its completed.
Since i'm not very experienced with offline apps i wonder, is this a legit solution?
Are we on the right path or at there alternatives? Isn't there a standard pattern of handling this type of issues?
We've also thought about a diff sync, which would only include a small portion of the JSON DB every time in the response (e.g by updated_at) but then what happens with deleted items? How do you know which ones should be deleted?
Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and looking forward for your thoughts!

How large is the JSON Object which you try to send with Django?
What kind of data are we talking about?
Since Python Dictonaries aka JSON require a large amount of memory when being used, I would try to avoid using dictonaries in python where possible. Especially in a production environment where a lot of data is being stored. There are many ways of optimising the whole thing, as there are tons of different internet articles.
Chunk your responses
One option could be instead of sending one big JSON object, sending multiple smaller ones. If you decrease the size of one request to smaller ones, you can get more throughput. The server needs less time to calculate a portion of the response. While the first response is being sent, the next one is already calculated.
Cache similar content
Instead of sending all content, just send the new one. As you mentioned, this can be done in the DB.
Maybe use SQL DB if possible
I know it sounds a bit weird, but I would use a SQL Database, since you already have one DB. Considering the fact that Django comes alongside a very handy DB Engine (or however the models are called), you will have faster processing speeds, as the whole process of converting data etc will be handled by django.
Since I don't know what app and data you are talking about, I can only assume some things. (And I am new here)
Hope this helps :)

Thanks Arian! Chunking is definitely something we must try out and thanks for brining it up.
Since you asked, the data is a quite simple JSON format. Its a json with 10 nested dicts. One of those dict values specifically is the one that has exploded in usage, eg can contain 1000-5000 entries in a list.
What is causing the delay at the moment is serializing this big json in django (from python objects). The queries are fine and optimized.

Idk if your 5000 entries long list may contain duplicates. One other option is to check if there are duplicates. Maybe introduce a data retention policy where for instance data ia being deleted when user accounts are inactive for a long time. Do you work with MongoDB? maybe consider loading the data via the app, so that each user has only read privilege for their stuff. Like just letting the user read the data directly through the DB via a temporary bearer token generated by your backend. Idk if that makes sense.

Plus you may add a compression to your data transmission, so that the data is being compressed, sent to the app user and then being decompressed.
